# How do I create a circle collision detection function in PyGame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make an agar.io-like game with pygame, for those who dont know, it's a game where you control a circle's movement with your cursor and eat other circle enemies to grow your size, Im new to python and I dont know much though, I figured out everything by myself for now but im stuck at the collision detection part, I want to create a function that returns true when it touches another circle. I tried searching for a solution but couldn't find any.

Comment: 2 circles are intersecting, if the distance between the 2 center points is less than the sum of the 2 radii.

Comment: Instead of checking the raw distance between the two objects, instead check the *squared* distance. You can avoid the relatively costly call to `sqrt` this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 circles are intersecting, if the distance between the 2 center points is less than the sum of the 2 radii. The distance between 2 points can be calculated by the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance):

```py
dist = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

In pygame this can be calculated by [`pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to).

If the 1st circle is defined by the center point `(x1, y1)` and the radius `radius1` and the 2nd circle is defined by the center point `(x2, y2)` and the radius `radius2`, then:

```py
centerPoint1 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1, y1)
centerPoint2 = pygame.math.Vector2(x2, y2)

collide = centerPoint1.distance_to(centerPoint2) < (radius1 + radius2)
```

`collide` is `True` if the 2 circles are intersecting.

If you want to avoid the square root operation, then you can use [`distance_squared_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_squared_to) and compare the square of both lengths:

```py
max_dist_square = (radius1 + radius2)*(radius1 + radius2)
collide = centerPoint1.distance_squared_to(centerPoint2) < max_dist_square
```

Comment: Note: if you use [`Sprites`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), you can simply use the [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle) function for this.